# If/Then statement does not execute properly

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have created various macros with If/Then but this time I have an issue with If/Then process. It does not execute properly for the second part of the If/Then after And . It only turns the values 0 for the offset that is before And. The format of the cells has no problem, because, when I change them positions it works fine for the one that is before And again. I am providing the code below.

```
For Each cell2 In Range("E7:E" & lastrow12)
    If cell2.Value = 0 Then
    cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value = 0 And cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0
    End If
    Next cell2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
For Each cell2 In Range("E7:E" & lastrow12)
    If cell2.value = 0 Then
        cell2.Offset(0, -2).value = 0
        cell2.Offset(0, -1).value = 0
    End If
Next cell2
```

`And` [is a boolean operator, it is used in conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator).

Answer (score 1):

The And function is a built-in function that is categorized as a Logical Function e.g True And True.

You cannot use to merge two statements. That said:

```
For Each cell2 In Range("E7:E" & lastrow12)
    With cell2
        If .Value = 0 Then
            .Offset(0, -1).Value = 0
            .Offset(0, -2).Value = 0 
        End If
    End With
Next cell2
```